# Unable to SUM column calculated by Array Formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I've used Array Formula to calculate the total price for an order and I have a manual column next to it to note what has been paid.  When I come to do a comparison of the two though, Google sheets appears unable to `SUM` the column created by Array Formula but has no problem with the manually created ones.

Is there a way around this?

I've made a dummy sheet illustrating the issue here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XZr3Kj2jq2jxjhU6nCfthdu9TBdxJKzdYW0uMpwOO7w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: to get rid of those zeros, try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN(A1:A)+LEN(B1:B)),IF(ROW(P:P)=1,"Cost",FIXED(A:A+B:B,2)),))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKqVd.png

Answer (score 1):

- instead of **`SUM`** use **`SUMPRODUCT`**

  **`=SUMPRODUCT(C:C)`**

  [image: 0]

Comment: So simple!  I'd googled for ages :)  Thank you!

Comment: @ClaireSpeed **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers**